# Direct limit commutes with n-simplex functor

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Use the universal property to show this:
$$
S_{\bullet}(\lim_{\xrightarrow[i\in I]{}}X_i,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \lim_{\xrightarrow[i\in I]{}}S_{\bullet}(X_i,\mathbb{Z})
$$
Where $S_{\bullet}(X_i,\mathbb{Z})$ is singular complex of a topological space.

I got stuck  with this exercise.The idea was to prove $S_{\bullet}(\lim X_i,\mathbb{Z})$ meets universal property in the category of chain of complex and for unicity of limit in that category to be able to conclude they are isomorphic.

I found if a Functor has adjoint, it preserves limits direct. I think "the realization geometry" is adjoint , but I wouldn't like to prove it in this way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: First, find a canonical map from the right hand side of the isomorphism to the left hand side. Now, you can show by hand this is a bijection for every $n$: it takes a bit of work, and there are more conceptual results implying the fact, but I see you're looking for an explicit argument!

Comment: I don't think that (a) this follows from the adjunction, (b) it is true in general. Notice that on the left we are looking at maps from spheres *into* the colimit (by the way, better avoid the term "direct limit" since it is just confusing, it is not a limit). We probably need that $X_i \to X_j$ are embeddings for $i \leq j$ (at least). The sentence "I found if a Functor has adjoint, it preserves limits direct." is not precise, you need to distinugish between left and right adjoints.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Page 78 [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/ATnotes.pdf) confirms your suspicion, I believe.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I agree with you, I need embeddings for $i\leq j$,but I dont know a how to give a counterexample without this hypothesis. Pedro suggest an example in page 78 but it isn't clear for me, could you explain me that example of spheres? please :)